# CDI ConversationScoped long-running Bean not working

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I got some problems understanding the Conversation scope of Weld or CDI.

In my JSF Faclets page i call:

```
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{viewBean.start}" />
        </f:metadata>
```

The bean:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

public void start() {
    if (conversation.isTransient()) {
        System.out.println("START CONVERSATION");
        conversation.begin();

    }
}
```

Now every time I refresh my browser, a new Conversation is started. Is that the correct behaviour? So why is the conversation always transient? No exception is thrown. The beans.xml is created and empty:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, this is the correct behavior.

**Long answer**: A conversation represents a "unit of work", which a such has to be demarcated explicitly. This is done with the explicit call of conversation.begin() - as you are doing already. Should you want to use the same conversation over more than one request, you have to *propagate* it - this is what you are *not* doing :-)

When you propagate a conversation, a conversation-id is appended to the request. This tells the container which conversation is wanted. When you just hit the refresh button without a conversation-id in your request a new conversation is generated for each request.

From the documentation:

> The conversation context automatically
>   propagates with any JSF faces request
>   (JSF form submission) or redirect. It
>   does not automatically propagate with
>   non-faces requests, for example,
>   navigation via a link.

If you need to propagate it manually, just add the conversation-id to the request:

```
<h:link outcome="/addProduct.xhtml" value="Add Product">
   <f:param name="cid" value="#{javax.enterprise.context.conversation.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

All that and much more is explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.0.Final/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1841).

Comment: @BalusC - what this "cleanup"-edit about? Anything wrong with my name and the word "cheers"? Any stackoverflow-directive I'm missing, or is that your personal taste? I'm not so convinced about the benefit...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) > "Can I use a signature or tagline?" If you disagree, bring it to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).